# Remove Children from Json object

Tags: json, c#-4.0, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a Serialized JsonObject in which i have to remove all except one json elements Or array from one of its child element.

```
{
"Index": "1",
"DoCID": "",
"Sin_id": "{xxxx}",
"Loan_LastModified": "2015-03-30T08:31:20-04:00",
"Col_1": null,
"col_2": null,
"ChildPair": [{
    "Index": 1,
    "Fields_35": "",
    "Fields_52": "",
    "Fields_1811": "PrimaryResidence",
    "Fields_4000": "discount point",
    "Fields_4077": null
}, {
    "Index": 2,
    "Fields_35": "",
    "Fields_52": "",
    "Fields_1811": "PrimaryResidence",
    "Fields_4000": "discount point",
    "Fields_4077": null
}, {
    "Index": 3,
    "Fields_35": "",
    "Fields_52": "",
    "Fields_1811": "PrimaryResidence",
    "Fields_4000": "discount point",
    "Fields_4077": null
},{
    "Index": 4,
    "Fields_35": "",
    "Fields_52": "",
    "Fields_1811": "PrimaryResidence",
    "Fields_4000": "discount point",
    "Fields_4077": null
}]
```

}
In childPair i need to remove all index except the first one.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: any code that you have tried so far?

Comment: yes , i have tried few, :
1) var o = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(raw);
 o.Children().Last().First().Next.Remove();
   var aa = o.Last.First.ToArray().ToList();

2)  foreach(var key in o.Children())
            {
                foreach (var item in o["ChildPair"])
                    {
                        if(item.Path != "ChildPair[0]")
                        {
                            item.Remove();
                        } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, something like this should work. I'm removing all ChildPair objects with an index greater than 1. If necessary one could change the predicate to do a similar task

```
class RootClass
{
    public string Index { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string DoCID { get; set; }
    public string Sin_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Loan_LastModified { get; set; }
    public object Col_1 { get; set; }
    public object col_2 { get; set; }
    public List<ChildPair> ChildPair { get; set; }
}

class ChildPair
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Fields_35 { get; set; }
    public string Fields_52 { get; set; }
    public string Fields_1811 { get; set; }
    public string Fields_4000 { get; set; }
    public object Fields_4077 { get; set; }
}

var json = @"{
                    ""Index"": ""1"",
                    ""DoCID"": """",
                    ""Sin_id"": ""{xxxx}"",
                    ""Loan_LastModified"": ""2015-03-30T08:31:20-04:00"",
                    ""Col_1"": null,
                    ""col_2"": null,
                    ""ChildPair"": [{
                        ""Index"": 1,
                        ""Fields_35"": """",
                        ""Fields_52"": """",
                        ""Fields_1811"": ""PrimaryResidence"",
                        ""Fields_4000"": ""discount point"",
                        ""Fields_4077"": null
                    }, {
                        ""Index"": 2,
                        ""Fields_35"": """",
                        ""Fields_52"": """",
                        ""Fields_1811"": ""PrimaryResidence"",
                        ""Fields_4000"": ""discount point"",
                        ""Fields_4077"": null
                    }, {
                        ""Index"": 3,
                        ""Fields_35"": """",
                        ""Fields_52"": """",
                        ""Fields_1811"": ""PrimaryResidence"",
                        ""Fields_4000"": ""discount point"",
                        ""Fields_4077"": null
                    },{
                        ""Index"": 4,
                        ""Fields_35"": """",
                        ""Fields_52"": """",
                        ""Fields_1811"": ""PrimaryResidence"",
                        ""Fields_4000"": ""discount point"",
                        ""Fields_4077"": null
                    }]}";

var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClass>(json);

res.ChildPair.RemoveAll(childPair => childPair.Index != 1);
```

If you want to skip null properties ( say DocID ) you can try:

```
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject, 
                        Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, 
                        new JsonSerializerSettings { 
                            NullValueHandling =NullValueHandling.Ignore
                        });
```

This will remove DocID or Sin_Id from the output if null.

.. and to remove DocID and Sin_id from the output whether or not they are null:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
JObject rootObject = JObject.Parse(json);

rootObject.Property("DoCID").Remove();
rootObject.Property("Sin_id").Remove();

var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject);

Console.WriteLine("Output: " + output);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Terry Lennox ...it worked like a charm..thanks a ton..

Comment: Hey Terry can you tell me how to remove all except Sin_Id and DocID
Thanks

Comment: If you don't ever need Sin_Id or DocID, just remove these properties from the class RootClass!

Comment: I know this to remove from class but i can't, the reason being that its used at other places by other developers, so i am being asked to remove from the output. Sorry for that.

Comment: No problem!, If you don't want them in the output, you need to set them to null, but also modify to have attributes on the two properties [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)], this way they won't appear in the output. I'll update the answer!

Comment: Thanks !! But in the class its already defined as
[JsonProperty("Sin_ID")],   so will replacing it with the one you say give issue to the work of other developers. Bcz changes in class Properties will be questioned to me . I hope u understand how it is..:) Thnx

Comment: You can then try setting the serializer to ignore null properties, I have updated the answer to include this, you won't have to change the class then.

Comment: I wish to remove these from json output whether null or not, doesn't matter..Thnx

Comment: Cool, then have a look at this https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm, I think this should work!

Comment: I know this should work ,but the json output got no parent here. :(

Comment: I'll post the code a bit later! We'll get the results we need!

Comment: Thanks for it Terry :)

Comment: I've added the update to the answer now, this will remove the two properties from the Json.